# What "require" statement to use Java library from Clojars

Tags: java, clojure, clojars

Most Clojure libraries give information not only on what to put in the `project.clj` file, but also how to `require` the library within the source file. For example, https://github.com/clojure/data.json provides a *Usage* section:

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))
```

I want to use a Clojars library (it’s a Java library), which is listed on Clojars: https://clojars.org/zololabs/jericho-html-parser. I have successfully added the dependency to my `project.clj` file, but I don’t know how to `require` it.

I have tried `(require '[zololabs.jericho-html-parser])` and numerous variants, but none seems to work. I have looked at the naming conventions of libraries I know how to require to see if I could discern the pattern, but I have not succeeded.

Is there a straightforward way to tell, based on the file name, Leiningen coordinates, or other information, how to `require` the library?

Comment: This isn't really a question about Leiningen; it's about how to use a library in Clojure.  You might want to change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't `require` a Java library from Clojure, you `import` one or more Java classes. For example:

```
(:import [net.htmlparser.jericho Source TextExtractor])
```

Then you use those classes via Java interop. e.g.

```
(Source. (java.net.URL. "https://yahoo.com"))
```

Note that you don't need to import Java classes already in the classpath in order to use them. You can avoid the import and just refer to them by their fully qualified name if you're going to use them once or twice:

```
(net.htmlparser.jericho.Source. (java.net.URL. "https://www.yahoo.com"))
```

Obviously you need to look up the Java library API first and understand how it works. In this particular case, see [here](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/).

Answer (score -3):

You have just discovered one of the inconsistancies in Clojure.

The short answer is that you are missing a colon, which is required for the `(ns ...)` form used in a source file:

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))
```

Note that since `ns` is a macro, the source file version doesn't require a single-quote before the left-square-brace.

The other case is using the `(require ...)` *function* at the REPL.  In this case, you need the syntax:

```
> (require '[clojure.data.json :as json])
```

where the `>` is the REPL prompt.  In this case, you are calling a *function*, so there is no colon before the `require`.  However, since the *function* is not a *macro*, you do need to quote the vector specifying the library name and its alias.